# Angular 5 component shows up / hides even though ngIf is false

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a small component that should show up after a timeout of 1500ms:

```
export class SmallComponent implements OnInit {
    public showComponent: boolean;
    private timeout: NodeJS.Timer;

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.showComponent = false;

        this.timeout = setTimeout(() => {
            this.showComponent = true;
            clearTimeout(this.timeout);
        }, 1500);
    }
}
```

The HTML related:

```
<div *ngIf="showComponent">
    <div class="small-component-container" [@fadeInOut]>
        <!-- stuff here -->
    </div>
</div>
```

What happens here is that the component HTML is showing up at the very beginning when the app is loading. Then immediately hides and after the 1500ms shows up again. This only happens when you first open the browser and go to the site. Why is that? I've never seen that before. I have been playing with the AfterViewInit hook in the parent component for a workaround but I don't know the real reason for it.

**UPDATE:**

After removing all components but SmallComponent I can see the issue shows up while the app is loading the first time and that's when I'm viewing the SSR application. If I run it though "ng serve" the issue does not appear.

**ANOTHER UPDATE**

If I use the isPlatformBrowser on that component and use that on an ngIf to render/not render the HTML this works. What seems to be happening then is that the SSR starts but ignores all flags in your component - this last around half a second - then the actual site renders and all the logic gets run. Like I say, if I exclude this from being rendered on the server then it starts to work. By the way, didn't understand that negative vote. To me this seems a very interesting issue/question around SSR and it's very useful element for your cheatsheet when implementing that on an Angular app.

Comment: you dont initially set a value to `showComponent`, that might cause issues

Comment: are you saying do not set it to false?

Comment: no, im saying initially set it to false, not undefined

Comment: @mast3rd3mon no it won't cause issues. Its value is `undefined`, which is a falsy value in Javascript.

Comment: Please update your question with an [mcve].

Comment: @trichetriche i know its a falsy value in js but thats the only out of place thing in the code

Comment: And maybe that's not the whole code. as @Igor suggested, it should be reproductible with a MCVE.

Comment: I'm struggling to get the repo scenario. I'm now testing locally and I can see this issue when I build the app for SSR. If I run it through ng serve I can't get that problem. I have commented all my code locally except that component that should appear with the 1.5s delay and still have the problem

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why setTimeout() fails here either, but I have another solution for you:

```
import { timer } from 'rxjs/observable/timer';

export class SmallComponent implements OnInit {
    public showComponent: boolean = false;

    ngOnInit(): void {
      const delay = timer(1500);

      const subscribe = delay.subscribe(val => { 
         this.showComponent = true;
      });
    }
}
```

Use an Observable as timer. This is supposed to work properly.